# Pandas "to_datetime" not accepting series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am new to pandas and am trying to convert a column of strings with dates in the format '%d %B' (01 January, 02 January .... ) to date time objects and the type of the column is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` .
if i pass in this series in the to_datetime method, like

```
print(pd.to_datetime(data_file['Date'], format='%d %B', errors="coerce"))
```

it all returns `NaT` for all the entries, where as it should return date time objects

I checked the documentation and it says that it accepts a Series object.

Any way to fix this?

Edit 1:
here is the head of the data i am using:

```
           Date  Daily Confirmed
0   30 January                 1
1   31 January                 0
2  01 February                 0
3  02 February                 1
4  03 February                 1
```

edit 2: here is the information of the data

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 179 entries, 0 to 178
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   Date             179 non-null    object
 1   Daily Confirmed  179 non-null    int64 
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 2.2+ KB
```

Comment: May be The `format='%d %B'` does not match

Comment: It does match,
if id do `print(pd.to_datetime(["01 January"], format='%d %B', errors="coerce"))`, it does return a date time object

Comment: Ok can you share some sample data ?

Comment: i have added the data to the post
(also all dates are strings)

Comment: It can't be converted to a datetime without a year.

Comment: But this `print(pd.to_datetime(["01 January"], format='%d %B', errors="coerce"))` works and defaults the year to `1900`

Comment: `print(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%d %B' , errors="coerce"))`
output: 
```
0   1900-01-30
1   1900-01-31
2   1900-02-01
```

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['30 January', '31 January', '01 February', '02 February', '03 February'], 'Daily Confirmed': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]})` , `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d %B", errors='coerce'))` is a datetime64[ns] Series with expected values.

Comment: There is a space after 30 January,
may thats why you cant reproduce it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you may be facing this issue because there are spaces around the dates in this column. To solve it, use `strip` before `to_datetime`. Here's a piece of code that does that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': 
                   ['30 January ', '31 January ', ' 01 February ', '02 February', 
                    '03 February'], 'Daily Confirmed': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1]})

pd.to_datetime(df.Date.str.strip(), format = "%d %B")
```

The output is:

```
0   1900-01-30
1   1900-01-31
2   1900-02-01
...
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. actually i checked that there were spaces to some dates and not others, so it was not uniform. a quick regex fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd 
dic =  {"Date": ["30 January", "31 January", "01 February", ] ,  "Daily Confirmed":[0,1,0]}
df =pd.DataFrame(dic)
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%d %B')
df
```

By default, it contains years as 1900. Because you did not provide year on your Dataframe
Output:

```
    Date       Daily Confirmed  date1
0   30 January      0          1900-01-30
1   31 January      1          1900-01-31
2   01 February     0          1900-02-01
```

If you don't want year as prefix of date. Please add the below code:

```py
df['date2']=df['date1'].dt.strftime('%d-%m')
df
```

```
    Date       Daily Confirmed  date1         date2
0   30 January      0          1900-01-30     30-1
1   31 January      1          1900-01-31     31-1
2   01 February     0          1900-02-01     01-2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

df['datetime'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d %B"))
```

**apply()** allows you to use python functions in series, here you may have to specify the year otherwise the default year (1900) will be set as default.

Good luck